# Django: IntegrityError on Model FormSet - Excluding required M2M field

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-forms

So I have a modelformset for a House model, which has an owners manytomany field, I'm excluding the owners field due to the fact that I want it to just automatically save the currently logged in users id as the owner - I *could* hack this with hidden fields, but would rather know how it's properly done.

For clarity, the Integrity Error is that owner_id can not be null, my attempt at fixing it by hardcoding just to see failed in the beginning of manage_houses

**views.py**

```
 def manage_houses(request):                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    HousesFormSet = modelformset_factory(House, form=ManageHousesForm)                                                                                                                                                                  

    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                                                       
        formset = HousesFormSet(request.POST)                                                                                                                                                                                               

        # failed attempt at fixing integrity error                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        for form in formset:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            form.owner_id = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                            

        if formset.is_valid():                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            if formset.save():                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                notice      = "Success! Your houses were updated in the system."                                                                                                                                                            
                notice_type = "success"                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            elif not formset.has_changed():                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                notice      = "Something went wrong! Your houses may not have been updated."                                                                                                                                                
                notice_type = "error"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        formset = SpecialsFormSet()                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    response_details = { 'formset': formset,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                     'fields':  ManageHousesForm.base_fields }                                                                                                                                                                          

    try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        response_details['notice']      = notice                                                                                                                                                                                              
        response_details['notice_type'] = notice_type                                                                                                                                                                                         
    except NameError:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    return render_to_response('houses/manage.djhtml', response_details)
```

**models.py**

```
class House(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        app_label = 'houses'                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    # Fields                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    owners          = models.ManyToManyField(User)                                                                                                                                                                                            

    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50)                                                                                                                                                                                         
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True, editable=False, unique=True)                                                                                                                                               
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=75)                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    def __unicode__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return self.name
```

Comment: Could you attach your models code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Django Documentation, this is what [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are for:

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key.